# What is SQL query to select data and AVG of data entries with 5 min intervals

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have 18 Energy meter readers which sends data every 5 minutes to SQL Server database.

After this, I pull that data and plotting it to the graph. The issue is that the line on the graph is not smooth, it looks like this:

[image]

Instead of seeing rippled line every 5min, I want to average all 18 readings and provide one AVG number at that time. So my question is, What SQL query should I use, to select all data, average it on 5min interval and prepare it for graph?

Here is database sample:

[image]

Comment: How's the data organized in the database? Can you add a few rows of sample data?

Comment: What is the best way to share that information? It won't let me add screenshot here and it doesn't give enough characters to fit a sample of data?

Comment: You can try https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: I have added a screenshot from database into the question. Please see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rounded down each timestamp to the nearest minute, but this should do it.

```
SELECT 
  dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, DoD), 0) as TimeStamp
, AVG(T_Energy_A) as AverageEnergy
FROM energyReadingsTable
GROUP BY dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, DoD), 0)
```

Comment: AHAHA It worked. That's exactly what I needed! Thank you very much! Since this is my first ever work with databases and creating web pages, You have saved me a lot if time :)  Many thanks once again!